# Jenkins exist in localhost:8080 and localhost:8084/jenkins/

Tags: windows, jenkins, continuous-integration, localhost

I'm new to Jenkins and have already installed it on to my windows operating system. But somehow I can access Jenkin in 2 places

1) I have a Tomcat server running on localhost:8084, when I type in http://localhost:8084/jenkins/ in the browser, the Jenkins login page is shown (but I can't log in to Jenkins due to incorrect password or username)

[image]

2) localhost:8080

[image]

Why does Jenkins exist in two places? Could someone please tell me why is this happening and how to fix it?

**EDIT 1:**

When I checked which process is listening to port 8084, as recommended by Stefan Hanke, this is the output

[image]

**Edit 2:**

after I checked localhost:8084/jenkins again

[image]

Comment: Have you played with [spinnaker](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker)? It seems to open a Jenkins instance at port 8084.

Comment: no, haven't seen it before.

Comment: Check whether Jenkins runs as service instance. Check `netstat -ano | more` which process is listening to port 8084 (and kill it).

Comment: @StefanHanke Thank you for the helpful suggestion. I have edited the questions and provided additional information, could you please have a look? Thanks again for your generous help!

Comment: Ah my bad. I somehow managed to read over that paragraph where you describe that you're running Tomcat at port 8084. So the Jenkins listening on port 8080 is the wrong one. Find out which PID is opening that port and just kill the process (`taskkill /PID XXX /T`). If you run it as a Service check out the [uninstallation instructions](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service#InstallingJenkinsasaWindowsservice-Uninstallation).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have run it from different platforms, both as a war file and a docker. Try terminating one port that is being listened to in Task Manager.